# How to update site changes on GCP from GitHub website

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform

I have been helping a friend make some changes to their website. The people that developed it before hosted it on GCP, and all code was pushed to GitHub. I was given ownership of the Git repository and invited by my friend to the GCP.

However, I do not know how to push the changes that are in the Git repository to the GCP to update the live site. I have taken a look through some tutorials, but they all show how to do it from scratch, but of course, this has already been done before and I am not sure if things are the same.

I have checked the source repository section in the GCP console, and there is nothing there. I am also locked out of the Firestore.

Could someone explain how I go about updating the live site with my changes committed to GitHub.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use the [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories). You can [Mirror a GitHub repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository) to our Cloud Source Repositories. Once that is done you can start to [Push a change to your app](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories#push_a_change_to_your_app).